# Execute Intelij IDEA code format when committing

Tags: github, gradle, intellij-idea

I would like to apply a code format action before I'm commiting.

Currently I have xml eclipse file that would define the format I would apply.

Since I have gradle and spotless I declared an action such as:

```
spotless {
        enforceCheck false
        java {
            licenseHeaderFile "${rootDir}/LICENSE"
            // licenseHeaderFile "${rootDir}/LICENSE"
            eclipse().configFile("eclipse/formater.xml")
        }
    }
```

That is triggered by a shell script that is a git hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

toFormat="$(git --no-pager diff --name-status --cached | awk '$1 != "D" && $2 ~ /\.kts|\.java|\.kt/ { print $NF}')"

echo "Will format the files:"
echo $toFormat | tr " " "\n"

for fileToFormatPath in $eligibleToFormat
do
  ./gradlew spotlessApply -PspotlessIdeHook="$(pwd)/$fileToFormatPath"
  git add $fileToFormatPath
done;
```

And so far it is working.

Now I would like to do it but directly using the declared IDEA xml formater such as:

```
<code_scheme name="formater" version="173">
  <JavaCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="ANNOTATION_PARAMETER_WRAP" value="1" />
  </JavaCodeStyleSettings>
  <JetCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="CODE_STYLE_DEFAULTS" value="KOTLIN_OFFICIAL" />
  </JetCodeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
    <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="120" />
    <option name="KEEP_LINE_BREAKS" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_CONTROL_STATEMENT_IN_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_DECLARATIONS" value="2" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_CODE" value="2" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_BEFORE_RBRACE" value="2" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_CHAINED_METHODS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS" value="false" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS_IN_CALLS" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_WITHIN_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_BRACES" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE" value="false" />
    <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="5=4" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="RESOURCE_LIST_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="EXTENDS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="THROWS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="EXTENDS_KEYWORD_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="THROWS_KEYWORD_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_CALL_CHAIN_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_SIGN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_SIGNS_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="ASSIGNMENT_WRAP" value="1" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="SMART_TABS" value="true" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

I don't find much idea on the internet, any suggestion ?

Comment: You can use IntelliJ IDEA [command line API](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-formatter.html) to reformat code and integrate it to a Gradle task. But please note that it does not optimize imports. Related requests: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211841 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180965

Comment: When I tried the command line API back then it told me that I could only run one instance of intelij idea.